# UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices throws AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to update a driver programmatically as follows:

```
var result = UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(
    IntPtr.Zero,
    @"MMDEVAPI\AudioEndpoints",
    @"C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\audioendpoint.inf_amd64_3cc700130e8033fe\audioendpoint.inf",
    0, 
    false);
```

The program runs in x64, but throws an AccessViolationException when above line executes. (attempt to read/write protected memory).

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet is missing the [DllImport] declaration of the function.  But I can tell that the one you use is wrong, the last argument must be `out bool`.  Surely the declaration you used is missing `out`, the only way you could have passed *false*.

Yes, this reliably generates an AVE when the native code tries to dereference the pointer.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for the access violation. Thanks a lot. Now the result still returned as false, so still have something else to figure out.... :)